# What's the meaning of "nimmy"?

Tags: word-meaning

> 'A-why,' says he, 'I was out a-hunting today, and I got away to a
>   place in the wood I'd never seen before. And there was an old
>   chalk-pit. And I heard a kind of a sort of humming. So I got off my
>   hobby, and I went right quiet to the pit, and I looked down. Well,
>   what should there be but the funniest little black thing you ever set
>   eyes on. And what was that doing, but that had a little
>   spinning-wheel, and that was spinning wonderful fast, and twirling
>   that's tail. And as that span that sang:
>
> **Nimmy nimmy not.**   My name's Tom Tit Tot.'

This content is from "Tom Tit Tot" in English fairy tales.

What's the meaning of "nimmy"?

Comment: If I had to guess, it's nonsense - likely designed to rhyme with "Tom Tit Tot". Lots of songs have nonsense words in them like "Tra-la-la"... they're just syllables to sing on.

Comment: Although I agree with Catija that for most modern speakers it would be nonsense, **nimmy nimmy not** could be an archaism meaning "catch me, catch me not".

Comment: _**"Nimmy-nimmy nick nack"**_ was apparently a guessing game:  https://books.google.com/books?id=pP4_AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA273&dq=%22nimmy%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwip2oepwuTMAhWC5oMKHZDrDoYQ6AEIJzAC#v=onepage&q=%22nimmy%22&f=false  _**Nimmy**_ on it's own may have meant "whimsical." https://books.google.com/books?id=rmkhAQAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA151&dq=%22nimmy%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwip2oepwuTMAhWC5oMKHZDrDoYQ6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=%22nimmy%22&f=false   I have never heard this word used except in the Tomtittot story, so you may not want to put a whole lot of effort into memorizing it.  :-)

Comment: @Catija - Nimmy may be a nonsense word, but it doesn't *rhyme* with Tom Tim Tot.

Comment: @nnnnnn ... No... But "not" does. My statement was unclear.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that this is a reference to the North of England dialect term 'Nimmy nimmy nack' A simple guessing game: *"Nimmy nimmy nack, Which hand will tha tak' ? The rector the left, Or the bonny bord's heft?"* - [The English dialect dictionary 1898](https://archive.org/details/englishdialectdi04wrig)

This is the most likely explanation as, for those that don't know, the story of [Tom Tit Tot](http://www.sacred-texts.com/neu/eng/eft/eft02.htm) is pretty much identical to the better known Grimm fairy story of Rumpelstiltskin. The excerpt quoted is from the point where the title character is overheard gloating that the young queen has failed to guess that his name is ...

*Answered as community wiki as @Adam has already referenced most of this in comments*

Answer (score 1):

"name me, name me not" is my best guess!